# iOS - 3.5" layout instead of 4" layout on device - works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, interface-builder, frame

I have XCode 6 project built with target OS as iOS 8.1 (I don't see earlier target in XCode).

All my view controllers are designed for iPhone 4 inch size. I see correct size when I launch my app on simulator (iOS 8).

However I get iPhone 3.5 inch layout on my iPhone 5C (4") - running iOS 7.1.1 - no matter what changes I make to storyboard. I tried changing storyboard settings like IB version to iOS 7.1 and later and so on, but to no avail.

The app runs totally fine, except that the top & bottom spaces appear black on my device - total height = 480 instead of 568.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you check the targets in `General` and `Build Settings`? In General, I can select value from 6.0 up to 8.2, in the other setting it's from iOS 4.3 on.

Comment: I saw - and changed them to 7.1 (my device iOS version) - for both project and target. Cleaned, reinstalled the app, but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution - as suggested by a kindred spirit on Apple forum:

- Include a 4" launch image to the asset catalog
- Clean up the project, delete derived data, delete the app from device
- Re-Run the app on device.
- 320 X 568 screen is there...woohoo....